# Updating the random number within a variable?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can a variable with a random number be updated. I'm using three.js. Here is my code. It works the first time it's called generating a sprite to a random location but then it just keeps going back to the same location. I thought that by calling the variables before they were used I would be updating them but it's not working.

```
        var locX = Math.floor((Math.random()*450)+1);
        locX *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
        var locY = Math.floor((Math.random()*250)+1);
        locY *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
        var locZ = Math.floor((Math.random()*350)+1);
        locZ *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;          

        function spriteAI1() {
        //console.log(c2Sprite.position.x);
        //console.log(ranLocX);
        //console.log(ranTen);
            if (c2Sprite.position.x > 30 && c2Sprite.position.x <= 450) { 
            c2Sprite.translateX( -10 );
            } else if (c2Sprite.position.x < -31 && c2Sprite.position.x >= -450) {
            c2Sprite.translateX( 10 );
            } else if (c2Sprite.position.z < 31 && c2Sprite.position.x < 31 && c2Sprite.position.z > -29 && c2Sprite.position.x > -29) { 
            locX;
            locY;
            locZ;
            //c2Sprite.delete;
            //scene.remove(c2Sprite);
            //console.log("AI1");
            c2Sprite.position.set( locX, locY, locZ );
            //scene.add( c2Sprite );
            //c2Sprite.clone;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want different values each call, declare the vars inside the function, not outside of it. As you currently have it, the vars are set once, and the function, however many times it's called, will reference those once-set values.